# ASP.NET WEB API 2 Works Locally But Not On Production Web Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've developed a new WEB API 2 that works great locally, however when I upload the same code to my production server (Arvixe in this case) all I get is a 404 when I call it. I've spent HOURS searching the web, reading forums, etc.. and have been able to find no resolution, so I'm asking here as my last effort.

I'm currently only testing with the default project that gets created when you do **New Project > ASP.NET Web API 2 Empty Project** in Visual Studio. This creates an empty project with a single `ValuesController`. You should be able the JSON response by called `/api/values`, but this doesn't even work.

I'm using Fiddler to test the API locally and on the web server.

```
http://localhost:1993/api/values    <--- works great
```

but

```
http://api.mydomain.com/api/values   <--- returns 404
```

Note: I created a subdomain "api" in this case, but everything for the code for the API is unchanged from when it was created.

Why in the world does this work locally but not on the production web server?

Comment: Check if all dll's are deployed, and the site is set up as an application in a .NET 4.5.1 app pool.

Comment: All the DLLs are there and it's running under ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated, but .NET 4.5.1 is installed and running on the server. I honestly don't see any reason why this shouldn't be working.

Comment: What about root of your application? Does is show default page on remote server?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: Tom, yes I did get it figured out. It ended up being a server-side issue with it not being configured correctly through IIS. With Arvixe I had to create the api.mydomain.com as its own website in order for it to function correctly. I'm not sure if this will be the case with your environment or not, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 3):

That the server returns  404 (Not Found)  may indicate a lot of things. However you can check using the following step:

1. Add a simple text document like readme.txt to your a folder sub-domain http://api.mydomain.com, and try to get access to that. If you can't access to that file, it means that the subdomain is not configured properly.
2. Publish the webservice using the "Publish" functionality, so that all DLLs will be copied.

After that,try to reach the Web ApI again.

Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

"Note: I created a subdomain 'api' in this case, but everything for the code for the API is unchanged from when it was created."

Above comment of your's is suspicious, you should publish your WEB API application in the root directory. Like if http://example.com is pointing to "MyExample" folder, then application should be published on "MyExample" folder.
After that you will be able access your api with http://example.com/api/{controller}/{action}

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple suggestion which I'm sure you have already considered, but have you opened the http port 80 on the server's firewall?

Also stick a plain old html file in the root of your project and see if the server serves it up.

Comment: Since 404 is a web server error, it's unlikely this would be returned if the web server port was closed.

Answer (score 0):

in your case, since you create a subdomain of 'api', you should try

```
http://api.mydomain.com/api/api/values
```

note that if you're using database for the function, you should change the connectionString in your web config

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the .net framework on you hosted domain that may be old one.

- Web api 2 is supposed on 4.5 framework.

Answer (score -1):

One reason for web api 2 method working OK on local machine but not on production server is that the method you are calling is working on local machine but not on remote server. In such a case you will receive message 404 or 500, and you would be lost why this routing is failing.
Why a method would fail on remote server, well there may be many reasons. For me, I was querying database in my method and my connectionString was not set for remote server.
One way of resolving it would be to put some very simple code in that particular method and test that routing is working. Then check your original code for errors reasons.

Comment: I am using web api2 extensively in my projects, and I shared my personal experiences to help everyone (as I have got lot of help by others).

Comment: I am using web api2 extensively in my projects, and I shared my personal experiences to help everyone (as I have got lot of help by others). Error 404 and 500 does not tell that your routing is OK but method is giving error. This may be confusing for many as they may be thinking that there is something wrong with routing/path. For my this effort I get down rating which is very surprising for me. I would love to know the reason by the great expert who down rated this reply. He must have courage to come forward and enlighten me with his wisdom. I am waiting.......